# numpy.savetxt keeps giving an error with 2d list

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

So I've been coding a 2d list that users can edit in python. At the end of this, I need to save the list into a txt file, then I get the error. This is the bit of code that's problematic:

```
tdlist = [["trash","laundry","dishes"],[1,2,3]]
items = numpy.array(tdlist)

savelist = open("list.txt", "w")
for row in items:
  numpy.savetxt("list.txt", row)
savelist.close()
```

**This is the wall of text error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/ToDoList/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1450, in savetxt
    v = format % tuple(row) + newline
TypeError: must be real number, not numpy.str_

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 113, in <module>
    numpy.savetxt("list.txt", row)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in savetxt
  File "/home/runner/ToDoList/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1452, in savetxt
    raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U21') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

Any help is great, thanks!

Comment: You can change the format specifier: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: `savetxt` iterates on the rows of a 2d array.  You don't need to do that yourself.  Read what it says about `fmt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems. the format problem is only one of them. You mixed two ways of how to write content to a text file.

Either you open the file, write to it, and close it again. Could be done like this:

```
tdlist = [["trash", "laundry", "dishes"], [1, 2, 3]]
items = numpy.array(tdlist)

savelist = open("list.txt", "w")
for row in items:
    savelist.write(", ".join(row) + "\n") #needs to be a string
savelist.close()
```

or you just use `numpy.savetxt` and write the whole items array in one step to a text file. Could be done like this:

```
tdlist = [["trash", "laundry", "dishes"], [1, 2, 3]]
items = numpy.array(tdlist)
numpy.savetxt("list.txt", items, fmt="%s") #like in the comments already mentioned, you need to specify a format here
```

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Ty for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
In [84]: tdlist = [["trash","laundry","dishes"],[1,2,3]]
    ...: items = numpy.array(tdlist)
```

Note that the resulting array is string dtype, even the integers:

```
In [85]: items
Out[85]: 
array([['trash', 'laundry', 'dishes'],
       ['1', '2', '3']], dtype='<U21')
```

As shown in the other answer, this can be written with a '%s'` (general string format):

```
In [86]: np.savetxt('test.txt', items, fmt='%s')
In [87]: cat test.txt
trash laundry dishes
1 2 3
```

Often data like this is written with columns of consistent type - string, label columns, numeric data columns, etc:

```
In [88]: np.savetxt('test.txt', items.T, fmt='%10s %s', delimiter=',')
In [89]: cat test.txt
     trash 1
   laundry 2
    dishes 3
```

Another approach is to make a structured array with string and integer fields:

```
In [92]: arr = np.array([(i,j) for i,j in zip(*tdlist)], dtype='U10,i')
In [93]: arr
Out[93]: 
array([('trash', 1), ('laundry', 2), ('dishes', 3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

That can be written with the same format:

```
In [95]: np.savetxt('test.txt', arr, fmt='%10s %d', delimiter=',')
In [96]: cat test.txt
     trash 1
   laundry 2
    dishes 3
```

`savetxt` iterates on the rows of the array, and for each writes

```
fmt%tuple(row)
```

where the `fmt` is either what was given, or a replication of the simpler one, with intersperced delimiters.